# samsung galaxys5 how much data space does apps take on the phone storage?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I have a samsung galaxys5, can you tell what applications uses a lot of space?

Comment: I think your question should be *how can I tell which applications uses a lot of space in my device?* and MANI's answer would fit it well. The current question is missing something integral.  How do we really tell you which apps are consuming how much space until you detail us **which apps are installed in your device**? Do you see the missing detail now!

Comment: Do you want only the apps intalled in just your phone memory and not the sdcard..?

Answer (score 0):

Open `Settings> Application manager> Downloaded> Sort by size`. Apps with larger size appears first on the list.